# Hiding a button sprite in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Please help me, I've been trying for hours to get this to work. I'm kind of new to this type of programming so bear with me. I'm trying to create a popover help image that has a close button in the top corner. When you click the close button the popover closes. sounds simple enough right? I've currently got it so that when the button is clicked the popover image closes, but i can't get the actual close button to go away at the same time. what am i missing here?

```
-(void) startGame
{

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    showHelp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"help.png"];
    showHelp.position = ccp(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2);
    [self addChild: showHelp];

    if (g_isFirst) 
    {
      showHelp.visible = YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        showHelp.visible = YES;
    }

GrowButton* button = [GrowButton buttonWithSprite:@"close_def.png"
                                         selectImage:@"close_def.png"
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(selCloseHelp)];
    float x = ADJUST_X(410)+(IS_IPAD()?60:0) + (IS_IPHONE5?44:0);
    button.position = ccp(x, ADJUST_Y(270)+(IS_IPAD()?60:0));
    [self addChild: button];
}

-(void) selCloseHelp 
{

  if (g_SoundFlag) 
  {
        [sd_button play];
        showHelp.visible = NO;
  }
}
```

my problem is that i have no idea what to add to make the close button hidden as well. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Add the button as a subview of showHelp.
2. make button a property ( like showHelp) and set its visible to NO also.

Comment: forgive me, but i have no clue how to make it a subview or a property. Do you have an example

Answer (score 0):

```
yourSprite.visible=NO;
```

if you used the visible property to set the sprite hidden it is very good approch to hide the objcet because if you set the **Visible=no** then sprite may not be created in memory thats why the memory will not be wastage.

simply do this stuff

Answer (score 0):

make the button a property and set

```
yourButton.hidden = YES;
```